# calculate distance b/w Bluetooth Low Energy device and android phone

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

i have BLE device. i want to get the RSSI values from that device. calculate the distance between android phone & BLE device. please send the procedure/code for that.

Comment: People here are not slaves, where you can come up with a requirement and ask for code. Go do something first, read android documents, search on Google before putting your question.

Comment: You cannot use the RSSI value for distance calculation, since it also depends on obstacles.

Answer (score 1):

There is no known way to compute the distance between a wireless transmitter and receiver based on RSSI. This is due to multipath effects in sending wireless signals in real environments. RSSI is not even monotonic decreasing over distance; if you take a receiver and measure RSSI while moving away from a transmitter, you may see the RSSI go up and down.

The way location is generally computed for devices like bluetooth low energy is to find the closest device of known location and approximate using that.

Answer (score 0):

Generally **last** byte is **RSSI** value .You can observer this value , changing

the movement of your device you can see change in it's value.